# Use LibComponentLogging in an app that uses RestKit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, logging, conflict, libcomponentlogging

RestKit uses [LibComponentLogging](http://0xc0.de/LibComponentLogging) to log on the Xcode console. I'd like to use the same library in my iPhone application, but the two following setups failed:

- Adding LCL as a library of my project causes a name conflict (as `lcl.a` already exists in the copied framework).
- Using `lcl.h` from `RestKit/lcl.h` causes LCL to use the default RestKit logger, so I always have the `restkit` prefix in my logs. LCL doesn't take my components configuration into account.

Is it possible to use this library or will I have to switch to another log system ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**RestKit 0.10.x**:

With RestKit 0.10.x you can use `lcl.h` from RestKit and add your components either to `lcl_config_components.h` from RestKit, or create your own configuration file and add an include for it to the `lcl_config_components.h` file from RestKit.

See also https://github.com/aharren/LibComponentLogging-Core/issues/18

**RestKit 0.20.x**:

RestKit 0.20.0 now uses an embedded variant of LibComponentLogging and all embedded parts of LibComponentLogging are prefixed with RestKit's `RK` prefix. This enables RestKit to be used in an application that utilizes a normal LibComponentLogging installation for its own logging, even if RestKit is installed as a Git submodule.

When used with CocoaPods and the `LibComponentLogging-pods` pod, all RestKit log components will be integrated into the normal `lcl_` symbol space. This way, all `lcl_configure_`... configuration functions will also cover RestKit's log components. If `LibComponentLogging-pods` is not used, RestKit's log components need to be configured via RestKit's `RKLogConfigure`... functions.

See http://0xc0.de/LibComponentLogging#CocoaPods for more information about LibComponentLogging and CocoaPods.

Comment: I don't think it's a proper way to add my configuration as I would modify the RestKit sources. Plus, RestKit is added as a GIT submodule, so its modified sources won't be pulled when someone does a `git clone` (the official RestKit repo is fetched instead). I see in the Github issue that you think it is "the only workaround", it makes me sad :( (congrats for your great work, btw !)

Comment: Right, if RestKit is integrated as a Git submodule, then this doesn't work. Perhaps we need to modify the original RestKit a little bit such that it can be configured to take the config files from the main project. I will have a look.

Comment: First version for testing: https://github.com/aharren/RestKit, and the corresponding [RestKit issue](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/914). Feedback is welcome.